# Use \sbweight and \lgweight with cfr-lm package

Tags: fonts, latin-modern

[cfr-lm](http://ctan.org/pkg/cfr-lm) provides `\sbweight` and `\lgweight` font weights.

1. With

   ```
   \renewcommand\bfdefault{sb}
   ```

   we can use this like default bold font. Is this the best way?
2. How can I use the `\lgweight` font weight with `\texttt` and `\ttfamily`?

Comment: `lmodern` realizes its `lighttt` option by using the light fonts when the font series is `m` and medium weight when the font series is “bold”. I guess that making this work with `cfr-lm` would require a new set of virtual fonts and suitable loading options.

Comment: `\renewcommand\mddefault{l}`? @egreg Why would I need to create a new set of virtual fonts? To make it possible to use the light weight of `tt` while continuing to use the medium weight for all other families without having to use additional commands or preamble workarounds, I would need to do something in terms of the family definition files and provide an equivalent package option to `lighttt`. But I don't see why that would require any additional virtual fonts? (And I'm not convinced setting this up would be a good idea given the number of possible combinations supported by the package.)

Comment: @cfr You surely know better.

Comment: @egreg I wouldn't bet on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To emulate what I think may be the effect of `lmodern`'s `lighttt` option, you could try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tt={tabular, lining, monowidth}]{cfr-lm}
\newcommand{\myalph}{Aa Bb Cc Dd Ee Ff Gg Hh Ii Jj Kk Ll Mm Nn Oo Pp Qq Rr Ss Tt Uu Vv Ww Xx Yy Zz 0123456789}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{t1clmt.fd}
%Filename: t1clmt.fd
%Original created by: tex clm-t1-drv
%Original created using fontinst v1.933

%THIS FILE SHOULD BE PUT IN A TEX INPUTS DIRECTORY

\ProvidesFile{t1clmt.fd}
   [2010/05/25 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/clmt. Hacked 2014/07/04.]

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{clmt}{\hyphenchar\font=\m@ne}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{m}{n}{
   <-8.5> clmtt8t8
   <8.5-9.5> clmtt8t9
   <9.5-11> clmtt8t10
   <11-> clmtt8t12
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{m}{sl}{
   <-> clmtto8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{m}{it}{
   <-> clmtti8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{m}{sc}{
   <-> clmtcsc8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{m}{scsl}{
   <-> clmtcso8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{bx}{n}{
   <-> clmtk8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{bx}{sl}{
   <-> clmtko8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{l}{n}{
   <-> clmtl8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{l}{sl}{
   <-> clmtlo8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{lc}{n}{
   <-> clmtlc8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{lc}{sl}{
   <-> clmtlco8t10
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{m}{ui}{<->ssub * clmt/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{m}{si}{<->ssub * clmt/m/scsl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{b}{n}{<->ssub * clmt/bx/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * clmt/bx/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{b}{sc}{<->ssub * clmt/bx/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * clmt/bx/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * clmt/bx/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{b}{it}{<->ssub * clmt/bx/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{bx}{ui}{<->ssub * clmt/bx/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{b}{ui}{<->ssub * clmt/bx/ui}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{l}{sc}{<->ssub * clmt/l/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{l}{it}{<->ssub * clmt/l/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{l}{ui}{<->ssub * clmt/l/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{lc}{sc}{<->ssub * clmt/lc/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{lc}{it}{<->ssub * clmt/lc/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{lc}{ui}{<->ssub * clmt/lc/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{sb}{n}{<->ssub * clmt/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{sb}{sc}{<->ssub * clmt/m/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{sb}{sl}{<->ssub * clmt/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{sb}{it}{<->ssub * clmt/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{clmt}{sb}{ui}{<->ssub * clmt/m/ui}{}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}


\renewcommand\bfdefault{sb}
\renewcommand\mddefault{l}

\begin{document}
  \myalph

  \textbf{\myalph}

  \ttfamily

  \myalph

  \textbf{\myalph}

\end{document}
```

What this does is substitutes the `m` weight for `sb`. Since you are declaring `\bfdefault` as `sb`, this effectively means that the medium weight will be used as bold when this font family is used. When you are using roman or sans, of course, you'll actually get `sb` because those families have that weight and the description files support it.

By setting `\mddefault` to `l`, you get the light weight as the normal, medium weight throughout. However, since only the typewriter fonts actually have this weight, it will have no effect on the weight used for roman or sans.

Note that this is definitely a hack and not at all correct, let alone elegant. Moreover, there are probably several things I've not thought of so please use with care and let me know. ***Caveat emptor...***

[image: Demi, medium and light]

The above document writes the file `t1clmt.fd` to the current output directory (normally the same directory as your `tex` file). This means that TeX will use this version of the file rather than the original one from the main `texmf` tree. To use this hack with another document, best would be to put the `t1clmt.fd` file produced in the same directory as your document.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but I don't understand. Without `t1clmt.fd` the result is the same as `\renewcommand\mddefault{l}` only.

Comment: @cornelius What do you mean 'without `t1clmt.fd`'?

Comment: I must put the `t1clmt.fd` file in a TeX input directory?

Comment: @cornelius The above document writes the file to the current output directory (normally the same directory as the file). This means that TeX will use this version of the file rather than the original one. To use with another document, best would be to put the file in the same directory as your document.

Comment: @cornelius I've edited my answer to incorporate this information. If this answer works for you (and no better comes along), don't forget to accept it so that other users searching can find the solution. (Disclaimer: accepting my answer will get me points. It will also get you points!) Accepting and/or up-voting answers is the local way of saying 'thanks'.

Comment: With `\renewcommand\mddefault{l}`, `\textsc{...}` don't works as it should.

Comment: @ddg 'don't works as it should [*sic*.]' isn't much to go on. If you have a question, please ask one and include a complete small document which can be used to reproduce the issue. However, if you mean that you get upright shape for the typewriter font when not using bold, that behaviour is normal. That is precisely what is supposed to happen. There is no small-caps in the light weight so the upright shape is substituted. If you switch to bold, you can use small-caps as those will come from the medium weight which has them.